# implementing code for customized mini(less squares, less pieces ) chess board 5x5

Tags: c#, java, c++, chess

implementing code for customized mini(less squares, less pieces ) chess board in java or c++ or even in c#

I just want help for making best moves.  and I don't need any graphical interface.

[image]

input will be given as

> "rnkrrp*p*p*****P*P*PRNKNR"

where

> Pawns: P
>
> Rooks: R
>
> Knights: N
>
> King: K

here small letters represents black pieces and capital letters represents white pieces and "*" represents empty square

and output like

> a2a3

if best move happened from

> a2 to a3

by application only. for every move.

in this no inter face is required because we give input direct as string.

first I started to understand 8*8 chess board programming in java, c++ ,c# but I facing problem to understanding in some cases.

many source codes which seen is attempting moves with predefined best moves list.

and  don't have a particular idea to solve this. I want suggestion start this and make this solved.

thanks. and sorry for poor english

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. Are you supposed to write a playable game? A GUI interface that users can interact with? Does the computer need an AI? How much is involved here?

Comment: @ean5533 I suspect you can use xboard or winboard for the actual board, so probably just the engine. (edit: in fact he says so - second paragraph.) But I don't think an optimised 'best moves list' is a problem - it's presumably just for openings anyway, so just ignore it and evaluate the rest of the available moves based on some sensible metrics?

Comment: sorry, not related with programming at all, but using so many ... is not improving your question.

Comment: here just one input of where pieces present at starting program and moves as output... no need to show board.....@ean5533

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to study how [alpha beta pruning works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning). There is a lot of literature about chess programming, I suggest you to start [from here](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/).  As a very little example, [look at my project here](https://bitbucket.org/Felice_Pollano/felpo-ii/src/5d10a59cdc8c/EngineTests/FullEngineSuite.cs). I pointed to a file that is a test in finding a best move. My engine is not optimized, but simple enought to get how it works. It does not mind if you are using a reduced keyboard, the algorithm is the same as soon you created a proper move generator and a keyboard evaluator ( usually material value is enought ).

Comment: well I'm looking your project. thanks for giving suggestion.

Comment: But I'm not clear what all the magic words (eg the one on line 81) really mean.

Comment: @FanZheng nothing really magic, just the standard FEN notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation